# Division formula

Tags: vba

Is it possible to do a division with formula in a cell?

I need the formula to be in the cell.

I have tried but not working.

```
Range("A1").Formula = "="& Range(Cells(4,5),Cells(4,9)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Comment: What's not working? What do you expect the resulting formula to be? What do you get? Where's the division in your current attempt?

Comment: I got a Run time error 13 "type mismatch". I should expect a formula for cell(4,5)/cell(4,9) in "A1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = 5

    Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Cells(4, lastCol).Address & "/" & Cells(10, lastCol).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible i make use of range and cells? Because I am also making use of another variable, LastCol. What i am seeing is Range("A1").Formula = "Cells(4,LastCol)/Cells(10,LastCol)"

Comment: @user1204868 see updated answer :) let me know if that's what youre looking for